# contar cuantas veces se repite un numero c#

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un programa que me diga cuales son pares y cuales no y cuales y cuantos numeros se repiten pero no me da cuantos numeros se repiten y no se cual que estoy haciendo mal este es mi codigo

```
int num;
            int entrada = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("¿Cuantos numeros vas a ingresar?", "Numeros"));
            int[] lista = new int[entrada];
            for (int t = 0; t < entrada; t++)
            {
                num = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese el numero" + (t + 1)));
                listBox1.Items.Add(num);

                if (Convert.ToInt16(num) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add("Los numeros pares son" + num);
                }
                else
                {
                    listBox2.Items.Add("Los numeros impares son" + num);

                }
                lista[t] = num;

                for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
                {
                    if (num== lista[i])
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add("Se repite el numero"  + lista[i]+"las veces que se repite son:"+i);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está mal, primero carga tu array con los numeros, despues analizalos y por ultimo mostra los resultados, así:

```
int num;
int entrada = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("¿Cuantos numeros vas a ingresar?", "Numeros"));
int[] lista = new int[entrada];

// Cargo mi array de numeros:
  for (int t = 0; t < entrada; t++)
  {
      num = Convert.ToInt16(Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese el numero" + (t + 1)));
      listBox1.Items.Add(num);
  }

// Ahora analizo mi array:
  int numPares = 0, numImpares = 0, numRepetidos = 0;

  // Recorro los numeros
  foreach(item x in listBox2.Items){
    // Verifico si es par o impar:
    if (x.Value.ToInt16(num) % 2 == 0) numPares++;
    else numImpares++;

      // Verifico si esta repetido
      foreach(item y in listBox2.Items){
      {
        if (x.Value.ToInt16(num) == y.Value.ToInt16(num)) numRepetidos ++;
      }
  }

// Muestro resultado:
  listBox2.Items.Add("Numeroes pares:" + numPares + " impares: " + numImpares + " repetidos: " + numRepetidos);
```

Saludos!

Comment: por ejemplo el item que pones ahi donde lo mandas llamar?

Comment: item es un objeto de una colección de items y con el foreach lo recorres. No probé si compila el código porque lo escribí desde el celular, pero ahí tenés el código casi listo para terminar tu programa.

Comment: a okey si esque lo cale y manda error en el item y por eso tenia esa duda